# Print JSON object from Perl webservice

Tags: json, web-services, perl, cgi, extjs

I am using Perl as my web-service.

I have my variables stored in pic1 and pic2 variables.
I want to make an JSON object from that and pass to the client side which is Sencha touch application(print that json object as done in "arch.twitter.com/search.json?q='test'") webservice.

I have done this much.

```
print header('application/json');
my %data = (img_one => $pic1,img_two => $pic2);             

my $json_text = new JSON;
$json_text = to_json(\%data);
print $json_text;
```

Please guide me in this problem

Comment: Probably want to `use` a module or two somewhere...

Comment: can you modify the script or give me a practical example?

Comment: The program you show already prints a JSON. What's the problem with it? How it is different from what you want to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what kind of modules are you using. CGI? CGI::Simple? Something different?

So I'll just give you very materialistic script to print simple JSON response.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %data = (img_one => 'pic1', img_two => 'pic2');

print "Content-Type: application/json\n\n";

print to_json \%data;
```

Comment: Yes I got the solution..what was the problem is I stored my file with .cgi extension